# Анимация на C

Tags: анимация, c

В рисованных мультиках иллюзия движения задается последовательной сменой кадров, каждый из которых фиксирует очередное положение движущегося объекта. Используя этот принцип, получить мультфильм, показывающий бегающего человечка. Не могли бы объяснить, получается мне нужно составить такую программу, которая будет последовательно выводить картинки (которые я должна до этого нарисовать сама) так, что получится анимация бегающего человечка, либо я должна спрограммировать деревья, горизонт, человечка, который будет бегать (и т.е. есть функция в C отвечающая за это движение? )? И еще, а где это должно отображаться? Наверняка не на консоли... Я просто впервые с этим столкнулась, либо не могли бы посоветовать,где хорошо расписана работа с движущимися объектами, сама сижу со страуструпом, но ничего путного не нашла =((

Answer (score 2):

Ну тут, как вы правильно заметили, 2 варианта. Первый - выводить картинки (это называется спрайты), второй - рисовать всё самому программно (например, в openGL/D3D).

По обоим вариантам есть куча литературы с примерами.

Comment: вот когда я пишу программы с массивами, результат он мне выводит на консоль, а, в данном случае, где это должно у меня отображаться?

Comment: Вы можете создать отдельное окно, в которое будете выводить графическую информацию. Или можно сделать полноэкранное приложение. Как многие 3D игры для компьютера. Консоль же - это текстовый интерфейс.